# How to call UI Controls method from ViewModel(MVVM)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I want to call AutoComepleteBox s PopulateComplete() from ViewModel 
how do i call it ?

Answer (score 2):

Behaviors using System.Windows.Interactivity are a great way to do this.

Take a look at this - http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=34 - in this case he is using it for a watermark but you could easily adapt the behavior... I often reference this blog post as a starting point.

The main thing about behaviors is that you get access to things that you couldn't events that you can't attach to in a view model, it takes a few minutes to figure them out but one evening on the couch reading some blogs and MSDN and you will be a big fan!

Comment: +1 this.  Behaviors are pretty cool... Wish they came out of the box for WPF like they do for Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

The View should handle everything to do with the user interface and view - ideally you'd call `PopulateComplete()` from the view itself.  Based on your comment on BrandonZeider's answer, I'd suggest you create an event on the ViewModel which is fired when the service method finishes, and put your `PopulateComplete()` call in a handler for that event, in the View.

Now you can use your ViewModel anywhere - if something needs to happen on a view when the service call completes, it can simply subscribe to the new event.

Comment: This is the way I've done it in the rare few cases where I need the VM to callback to the View. Just expose an event on the VM and allow the View to hook into it if it wants to.

Answer (score -1):

There are several different ways to accomplish this, it just depends on what your trying to do...from where in your ViewModel are you trying to call PopulateComplete()? For example, if you are in an instance of [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx), you can pass in the control as a parameter, cast it and call your method.

Based on your comment, I would approach this a little different way. It's going to involve some amount of workaround because of the limitations of the control.

Add an event listener to the view in the code behind, listening to the collection change event of the collection in your view model. Then you can call PopulateComplete() in the event handler. You're going to need a reference to your ViewModel in your View for this to work.

Another option would be to pass a reference to the AutoComepleteBox to the ViewModel when the View loads (using an EventTrigger), and storing this reference in a private field. Then when your web service call returns, using this reference to call PopulateComplete().

Comment: I have service method which load List and that list i have Binded to Autocompelete box ItemsSource property. Now in service method after loading each Item To list I want to call the Method of AutoCompeleteBox which will render drop down from that List;